# JSP page to word file displays "Unable to open the document, File appears to be corrupt" on Google Docs

Tags: java, jsp

I am converting a jsp page to word file that is going to be read on mobile but I got the error as stated in the title.

Here are my codes for the conversion:

```
<%
String strMimeType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
response.setContentType(strMimeType);
response.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; 
filename=test.doc");
%>
```

I don't get it why the file is corrupted on mobile while it is not on a desktop. Please help, thank you.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the JSP. Seems to be a problem in the file.

Comment: Hmm. I've removed all the unnecessary codes and put only "test" after the jsp codes, same problem still. Can you please elaborate more on "problem in the file"?

Comment: "the file is corrupted on mobile while it is not on a desktop": most likely it would not work no matter how you transfer it.